# QT Canvas3D and Cesium

Tags: javascript, qt, cesiumjs, canvas3d

Recently QT introduced the "Canvas3D" Project, which basically allows you to draw OpenGL via Javascript. ie, native WebGL.

That sounds great to use cesiumJS (https://cesiumjs.org/).

Is  possible to use CesiumJS with Qt Canvas3D project? How can i do it?

Comment: Seems like this question has been superseded by [your next one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018619/qt-graphicwebview-segmentation-fault-sigsegv-when-loading-cesiumjs-with-natura).  Does this one still need an answer?

Comment: Oops - Wasn't familiar enough with Qt.  Canvas3D is very different from WebView in Qt.