# Qt GraphicWebView Segmentation fault (sigsegv) when loading cesiumJS with Natural earth

Tags: qt, webview, segmentation-fault, qwebview, cesiumjs

I created a Qt widget project and added a webEngine or webKit. On webEngine or webKit I set the url to a localhost and loaded the CesiumJS default HelloWorld.html.  JUST IT.

When I selected "natural earth" as map, the application has trhow a SIGSEGV error (segmentation fault).

What in Qt can throw this error? how can i avoid this. 
Is there any webView configuration (memory limit, Local Storage, etc)?

This is my Main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtWebEngine 1.1
Window {
    visible: true

    width: 860
    height: 460

       WebEngineView {
           id: webview
           url: "http://localhost:8080/apps/"
           anchors.fill: parent
       }
}
```

This is Main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtWebEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QtWebEngine::initialize();
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

this error

```
Stopped in thread 18 by: Exception at 0x7fee64cfe26, code 0x0000005: read access violation at : 0x0, flags=0x0 (first chance).
```

here is the stack

```
0   ig7icd64            0x7fee64cfe26   
1   DrvSetCallbackProcs ig7icd64        0x7fee6ba31f9   
2   DrvSetCallbackProcs ig7icd64        0x7fee6ba52e0   
3   DrvSetCallbackProcs ig7icd64        0x7fee6be4165   
4   DllMain ig7icd64        0x7fee66d058d   
5   DllMain ig7icd64        0x7fee6680416   
6   QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall    Qt5WebEngineCored       0x181a7a365 
7   IsSandboxedProcess  Qt5WebEngineCored       0x186b975b7 
8   IsSandboxedProcess  Qt5WebEngineCored       0x186a92a7d 
9   IsSandboxedProcess  Qt5WebEngineCored       0x186aaa97b 
10  IsSandboxedProcess  Qt5WebEngineCored       0x186a726aa 
11  IsSandboxedProcess  Qt5WebEngineCored       0x186a8a714 
12  IsSandboxedProcess  Qt5WebEngineCored       0x186b192dd 
13  IsSandboxedProcess  Qt5WebEngineCored       0x186a6c0e0 
14  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall    Qt5WebEngineCored       0x183938698 
15  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall    Qt5WebEngineCored       0x1839392c1 
16  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall    Qt5WebEngineCored       0x1839320ca 
17  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall    Qt5WebEngineCored       0x183938e11 
18  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall    Qt5WebEngineCored       0x1802efe5d 
19  IsSandboxedProcess  Qt5WebEngineCored       0x186a6ea6a
```

Comment: Can you post this test project for download someplace?

Comment: the project is the default quick Qt project, with the fallowing code on the questions (edited)

Comment: What OS? What spec? Have you overwritten defaults?